# Ajax POST delete multiple items with the same name Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, post

I'm trying to delete multiple Items with the same name in my web app. But it's giving me an error 500 when I do the POST.

This is my Form Code

```
  <form method="POST" name="deleteFormAdd" id="deleteFormAdd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />

                <!--Asset ID set to hidden so the User can't see it-->
                <input type="hidden" th:each="deleteCategory, itemStat : ${DeleteCategoryObject}" 
                th:name="assetID" 
                th:value="${deleteCategory.assetID}"/>

                <!-- For showing all the Asset to be deleted -->
                <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" type="text" 
                th:each="deleteCategory, itemStat : ${DeleteCategoryObject}" 
                th:name="${DeleteCategoryObject[__${itemStat.index}__].assetType}" 
                th:value="${deleteCategory.assetType}" 
                disabled="disabled"/>  

                <br></br>
                <input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Yes" th:onclick="'javascript:submitForm(\'deleteFormAdd\',\''+@{/delete-asset}+'\')'" />
                <button type="reset" onclick="window.location.href = 'manage-assets.html';" class="btn btn-default btn-block"> Cancel</button>
              </form>
```

Submit Form Ajax

```
    function submitForm(formID, url){
    var formData = new FormData($("#" + formID)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        data : formData,
        type : "POST",
        enctype : "multipart/form-data" , 
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        success : function(data) {
            if (data.status == 1) {
                openAlertDialog("Success", "The Asset type has been deleted!", "Continue", "manage-assets");
            } else {
                openAlertDialog("Error", data.message, "Continue", "manage-assets");
            }
        },
        error : function(data) {
            openAlertDialog("Error", data.message, "Continue", "manage-assets");
        },
    });
}
```

Spring Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete-asset", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String deleteAsset(@ModelAttribute List<AssetCategory> assetCategories) {
    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
    if (assetCategories != null && !assetCategories.isEmpty()) {
        String[] arr = new String[assetCategories.size()];
        for (int i =0; i < assetCategories.size(); i++) {
            arr[i] = assetCategories.get(i).getAssetID();
        }
        assetService.deleteAssets(arr);
        result.addProperty("result", "Success");
        result.addProperty("status", 1);
        result.addProperty("message", "Asset Deleted!");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Spring Service

```
    @Override
public AssetCategory deleteAssets(String[] assetID) {
    return dao.deleteAssets(assetID);
}
```

Spring DAO

```
    @Query("Delete From AssetCategory A WHERE A.assetID IN (:assetID)")
public AssetCategory deleteAssets(@Param("assetID") String[] assetID);
```

Spring Console Error

> Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface] with root cause
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface

This is the Form Data (it contains the asset ID's)

[image]

Comment: *But it's giving me an error 500*, to be noted that [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) means that something is went wront on the server side (in your case its Spring). please check on spring logs for more clue, i do suspect, it might be the deletion process itself instead of the ajax.

Comment: You're getting an error message on your Spring console. Post it. (Also, use `List<String>`; it's easier for everyone.)

Comment: I updated the post and included the error in the console

Comment: Possibly not related, but .... Why does `deleteAssets(@Param("assetID") String[] assetID);` return an instance of `AssetCategory` (as opposed to `void` or a `List` - eg where would it get that instance) ?   Check out the differences between `@Query`, `@Modifying` and `deleteBy` - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-deleteby has a good summary.

Comment: I changed it base on baeldung site. But still it shows error 500.

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue with your ajax function. Check with below:

```
function submitForm(formID, url) {
var assetIdList = [];
var assetIdObj;
$("#" + formID).find('input[name="assetID"]').each(function () {
    assetIdObj = {};
    assetIdObj.assetID = $(this).val();
    assetIdList.push(assetIdObj);
});

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: {assetCategories: assetIdList},
    type: "POST",
    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status === 1) {
            openAlertDialog("Success", "The Asset type has been deleted!", "Continue", "manage-assets");
        } else {
            openAlertDialog("Error", data.message, "Continue", "manage-assets");
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        openAlertDialog("Error", data.message, "Continue", "manage-assets");
    },
});
}
```

Update this html code from:

```
<input type="hidden" th:each="deleteCategory, itemStat : ${DeleteCategoryObject}" 
            th:name="assetID" 
            th:value="${deleteCategory.assetID}"/>
```

To this:

```
<input type="hidden" th:each="deleteCategory, itemStat : ${DeleteCategoryObject}" 
            name="assetID" 
            th:value="${deleteCategory.assetID}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `multipart/form-data`. So, your request header has `multipart/form-data` Content-Type which have data as form type. like key=value.

So just remove `@ModelAttribute` annotation and add `consumes` properties to your mapping annotation.

```java
//if you're using spring version more than 4.3, use below @PostMapping for readability
//@PostMapping(value = "/delete-asset", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete-asset", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String deleteAsset(List<AssetCategory> assetCategories) {
    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();

    //you can use apache's commons-collection
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(assetCategories)) {
        //and you can also use stream api
        String[] arr = assetCategories.stream()
                               .map(AssetCategory::getAssetID)
                               .toArray();
        assetService.deleteAssets(arr);
        result.addProperty("result", "Success");
        result.addProperty("status", 1);
        result.addProperty("message", "Asset Deleted!");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```